# NDSolve with extra parameters as a function

Tags: plotting, differential-equations, pdf-format, table

I have a forced heat PDE with some parameters, and my goal is to define a function as the numerical solution of the PDE with specified parameters. I have tried the following (got the idea from [this post](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/159021/how-to-define-a-function-involving-ndsolve-and-another-pde))

```
g[x_, t_, k_?NumericQ, a_?NumericQ, L_?NumericQ, T_?NumericQ] := 
First [f[x,t] /. NDSolve[{D[f[x, t], {t, 1}] - k D[f[x, t], {x, 2}] == (Exp[-x^2/(2a^2)] / Sqrt[2 Pi a^2]) f[x,t], 
f[x, 0] == L - Abs[x], f[L, t] == f[-L, t] == 0}, f, {x, -L, L}, {t, 0, T}]];
```

and then I want to plot `g` several sets of `k,a,L,T`. I have put `?NumericQ` since these are going to be numerical values. Now when I try a specific set of parameters, say `sln = g[x,t,1,1,1,1]`, Mathematica v13.1 seems to generate an interpolation (although with an `NDSolve::mxsst` error). However, I do not know how to Plot the result, since something like

```
Plot3D[y[x, t] /. sln, {x, 0, 1}, {t, 0, 1}]
```

generates errors (I would actually prefer a `Manipulate[Plot[y[x,t]/.sln,{x,0,1}],{t,01}]` so that I can see how the solution develops over time).

Is there a way to resolve this? Furthermore, since I need to generate many of these plots in a given range of parameters (say `0.2<a<2` and `0.1<k<1` both with `0.1` steps), I was wondering if there is a way to automatically produce all these plots without needing to manually replace the parameters for each plot? My guess is that this is doable with a `Table` but I don't know how exactly.

Comment: (1) Have you seen `ParametricNDSolveValue[]`? (2) If the time integration didn't finish (`NDSolve::mxsst`?), then adjust the time domain in the plot to how far the integration got.

Comment: @MichaelE2 I am trying `ParametericNDSolveValue` now. Is there a way to pass the interval sizes `L,T` as parameters too? (when I try it gives an error that says there are too many parameters).  (2) How can I find how far the integration has got?

Comment: Have a look at the documentation, for example [HeatTransferPDEComponent](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/HeatTransferPDEComponent.html) that has examples of plotting the solution.